# Where is the database saved in a device?

Tags: android, database

I have created a database for my app. In the emulator i can find the database at the path `data/data/app_name/databases/db_name.db` . When i install the app on a device,where can i find this db file?

Comment: at the same place ... But you cant access it without root

Answer (score 2):

The file is located in the same path. The difference with the emulator is that you need a rooted phone to access the same path

Comment: my phone is rooted,but i cant find the db file there..also,the database in the app works fine so where is the problem?

Comment: from the file manager, i can find the folder data,but inside there is no folder data,there are some folders with the package names of other apps installed on my device

Comment: try running adb shell ls /data/data/yourprocess and look for the output... what file manager are you running?

Comment: True .... filemanager should be running as su.... root is not enough ... ive just chech it with ES ... it doesnt show me data folder .... terminal emulator and su and then ls - works

Comment: i m going to the terminal emulator from my device, i type adb shell ls /data/data/package but i m getting error not device found..

Comment: have you plugged in your mobile?

Comment: i must write this command from the pc cmd or from the mobile terminator?

Comment: so i plug my device with usb on the pc,i open the cmd and then where i have to go to use the adb shell etc?

Comment: i m gettinf the same result...error:device not found...device must be in debug mode,right?

Answer (score 0):

For get this address either a device and emulator use this code:

```
File root = android.os.Environment.getDataDirectory();
String direct = root.getAbsolutePath() + "/data/app_name/databases/";
```

Finally, you'll get the same path: `data/data/app_name/databases/`